# What can mean “over toward“ together?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, american-english, adverbs

> I went up on the peak of the little mountain and ran my eye **over** the contiguous vicinity. **Over toward** Summit I expected to see the sturdy yeomanry of the village armed with scythes and pitchforks beating the countryside for the dastardly kidnappers. But what I saw was a peaceful landscape dotted with one man ploughing with a dun mule. Nobody was dragging the creek; no couriers dashed hither and yon, bringing tidings of no news to the distracted parents.
>
> *[[The Ransom of Red Chief by O. Henry](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Ransom_of_Red_Chief)]*

What is “over toward“? Is it two prepositions or an adverb + a preposition?

---

My first guess is that “over” means the previously mentioned place.

> **over**
>
> …
> ADVERB
> …
> 1.1 In or to the place mentioned or indicated.
>
> *‘over here’
>
> ‘come over and cheer us up’*
>
> *[[Oxford US English Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/over)]*

If you follow this definition, the “over” could substitute “the contiguous vicinity” (previously mentioned place) to avoid repeating:

***[In the contiguous vicinity] toward** Summit I expected to see the sturdy yeomanry of the village armed with scythes and pitchforks beating the countryside for the dastardly kidnappers.*

However, in such use, “over” acts as a pronoun. Why is it an adverb?

---

My second guess is that “over” is a repetition of the preposition “over” from the previous sentence:

*“I … ran my eye **over** the contiguous vicinity. **Over toward** Summit I expected to see…”*

In this case, «over» could mean:

> **over**
>
> PREPOSITION
> …
> 1.2 Extending above (a general area) from a vantage point.
> *‘views over Hyde Park’
> ‘This area has great views over the rear garden through large windows and a set of patio doors.’*
> …
> *[[Oxford US English Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/over)]*

Then the general meaning may be:

*“I … ran my eye **[above from a vantage point]** the contiguous vicinity. **[Above from a vantage point] toward** Summit I expected to see…”*

Comment: ***over + toward X = away from here + in the direction of X***. There's nothing unusual about combining / chaining terms like that - we can even have *over + **there** toward X = [**emphatically**] away from here + in the direction of X*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. Please give a reference to a dictionary definition or some grammar source that confirms your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

"Over toward" is a colloquial phrase meaning simply "in the direction of." There is extremely little difference between "toward" and "over toward;" the one thing that "over" adds to the phrase is a vague sense of increased distance, depending on context. Otherwise it is essentially a filler word.

Comment: Over is used a lot as a filler word in American English- for example in the Drifters' 1965 song entitled "Come on over to my place".

Comment: Please give a reference to the dictionary definition suitable to your explanation.

Comment: _“**colloquial** (of language) used in ordinary or familiar conversation; **not** formal or **literary**” [[Oxford US English Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/colloquial)]._ The quote is not from colloquial language, but literature.

Comment: The story is written in a colloquial voice. If this is not clear from the beginning, it should become so as the third paragraph opens: **Bill and me had a joint capital of about six hundred dollars . . .**

Comment: @JeffreyCarney: Not to mention which I see the *first* paragraph includes "during a moment of temporary mental apparition", which obviously should be "mental **aberration**". Which arguably suggests we should expect even more "deviation from standard use of language" than that implied by "colloquial" as opposed to "formal, literary" :)

Comment: @JeffreyCarney What signs of a colloquial voice has “_Bill and me had a joint capital of about six hundred dollars . . ._?” Even if this is a colloquial voice, the answer is still not convincing, because the author did not provide any references confirming his opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is nothing abnormal in “mental apparition”. This fiction literature, so an author has the right to use means of artistic expression. “Apparition — something you believe, imagine, or dream you see, esp. the form of a person; ghost” [[Cambridge American Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/apparition)]. So “mental apparition” is something like hallucination or illusion in a mind. I think, the word “apparition” was intentionally used, because it looks similar to “aberration”, to create the wordplay “mental apparition“/“mental aberration“. (1/2)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Moreover, this is a quotation of oral speech: _“It was, **as Bill afterward expressed it**, 'during a moment of temporary mental apparition'...”_ Therefore, “mental apparition” is definitely a colloquial voice. “Over toward” is not in a quotation of character's oral speech. It is in the author's written speech. (2/2)

Comment: @JavaLatte “Come over to” is an idiom.  _“**Come over to** idiom — to make a social visit to (a place) // Why don't you come over to my place after work?”_ [[Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20over%20to)].

Comment: _“A filler word is an apparently meaningless word, phrase, or sound that marks a pause or hesitation in speech”_ [[thoughtco.com](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-filler-word-1690859)]. Is there a need to fill in a pause or hesitation in speech in the given quotation? I do not think so. Please give a reference to a source where “over“ is classified as a filler word.

Comment: @Eagle if you insist that something is "literary" simply because it is a published work of fiction I can't really help you. As has been pointed out by multiple users, *TRoRC* is indeed written in a lowbrow and colloquial voice, and "over toward" is a rather colloquial turn of phrase. For reference see [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/over#Preposition) section **Preposition** def. 1.2 (and quotations) and the usage notes at the bottom of the section.

Comment: The «multiple users» in fact are the two users whose arguments are dubious. In your argumentation, there is a contradiction: a preposition can not be at the same time a filler word. It is very doubtful that this is a preposition at all because in this case, one preposition goes right after another preposition: over (1) toward (2). I think that it is rather an adverb + a preposition. _„**over**…ADVERB…1.1 In or to the place mentioned or indicated. ‘over here’ ‘come over and cheer us up’” [[Oxford US English Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/over)]_

Comment: @Eagle Perhaps *filler* is not the correct term to use: "semantically unnecessary but required by idiom" would be a better way to describe it. The semantic minumum would be "come to my place": in British English one would add **over**- "Come **over** to my place*, and in American English one can also add **on** - "Come **on over** to my place".

Comment: @JavaLatte _“**idiom** — A group of words established by usage as having a meaning **not deducible from those of the individual words** (e.g., rain cats and dogs, see the light)” [[Oxford US English Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/idiom)]._ The idiom is another case. An idiom can't be understood on basis of meaning of words. It can't require something because it is just a historically established combination of words. To understand why an idiom contains some words, you need to study its history. I am not ready to study this idiom now.